# while loading BMP the biSizeImage always 0

Tags: c++, image, bitmap, pixel

I'm trying to load a BMP image using this method :

```
int TextureManager::LoadBMP(std::string path, unsigned int &texture)
{
    unsigned char* datBuff[2] = { nullptr, nullptr }; // Header buffers

    unsigned char* pixels = nullptr; // Pixels

    BITMAPFILEHEADER* bmpHeader = nullptr; // Header
    BITMAPINFOHEADER* bmpInfo = nullptr; // Info 

    std::ifstream file(path, std::ios::binary);
    if (!file)
    {
        std::cout << "Failure to open bitmap file.\n";

        return 1;
    }

    // Allocate byte memory that will hold the two headers
    datBuff[0] = new unsigned char[sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)];
    datBuff[1] = new unsigned char[sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)];

    file.read((char*)datBuff[0], sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
    file.read((char*)datBuff[1], sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));

    // Construct the values from the buffers
    bmpHeader = (BITMAPFILEHEADER*)datBuff[0];
    bmpInfo = (BITMAPINFOHEADER*)datBuff[1];

    // Check if the file is an actual BMP file
    if (bmpHeader->bfType != 0x4D42)
    {
        std::cout << "File \"" << path << "\" isn't a bitmap file\n";
        return 2;
    }

    // First allocate pixel memory
    pixels = new unsigned char[bmpInfo->biSizeImage];

    // Go to where image data starts, then read in image data
    file.seekg(bmpHeader->bfOffBits);
    file.read((char*)pixels, bmpInfo->biSizeImage);

    unsigned char tmpRGB = 0; // Swap buffer
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < bmpInfo->biSizeImage; i += 3)
    {
        tmpRGB = pixels[i];
        pixels[i] = pixels[i + 2];
        pixels[i + 2] = tmpRGB;
    }

    // Set width and height to the values loaded from the file
    unsigned int w = bmpInfo->biWidth;
    unsigned int h = bmpInfo->biHeight;

    /TODO:***************GENERATING TEXTURES*******************/

    // Output a successful message
    std::cout << "Texture \"" << path << "\" successfully loaded.\n";

    // Delete the two buffers.
    delete[] datBuff[0];
    delete[] datBuff[1];
    delete[] pixels;

    return 0; // Return success code 
}
```

but the `bmpInfo->biSizeImage` always = 0 , so I have searched and found that I can find out the size in bytes of the bitmap data by multiplying the width by height by (bpp / 8), so I edit the function to be like this :

```
int TextureManager::LoadBMP(std::string path, unsigned int &texture)
{
    unsigned char* datBuff[2] = { nullptr, nullptr }; // Header buffers

    unsigned char* pixels = nullptr; // Pixels

    BITMAPFILEHEADER* bmpHeader = nullptr; // Header
    BITMAPINFOHEADER* bmpInfo = nullptr; // Info 

    std::ifstream file(path, std::ios::binary);
    if (!file)
    {
        std::cout << "Failure to open bitmap file.\n";

        return 1;
    }

    // Allocate byte memory that will hold the two headers
    datBuff[0] = new unsigned char[sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)];
    datBuff[1] = new unsigned char[sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)];

    file.read((char*)datBuff[0], sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
    file.read((char*)datBuff[1], sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));

    // Construct the values from the buffers
    bmpHeader = (BITMAPFILEHEADER*)datBuff[0];
    bmpInfo = (BITMAPINFOHEADER*)datBuff[1];

    // Check if the file is an actual BMP file
    if (bmpHeader->bfType != 0x4D42)
    {
        std::cout << "File \"" << path << "\" isn't a bitmap file\n";
        return 2;
    }

    DWORD       FileDataSize;
    DWORD       ActualDataSize;
    LONG        AjustedWidth;
    LONG        WidthOver = 0;      

    if (((bmpInfo->biWidth * (bmpInfo->biBitCount / 8)) % 4) != 0)
    {
        WidthOver = 4 - ((bmpInfo->biWidth * (bmpInfo->biBitCount / 8)) % 4);
    }
    AjustedWidth = bmpInfo->biWidth + WidthOver;
    ActualDataSize = bmpInfo->biWidth * bmpInfo->biHeight * (bmpInfo->biBitCount / 8);
    FileDataSize = AjustedWidth * bmpInfo->biHeight * (bmpInfo->biBitCount / 8);


    // First allocate pixel memory
    pixels = new unsigned char[FileDataSize];

    // Go to where image data starts, then read in image data
    file.seekg(bmpHeader->bfOffBits);
    file.read((char*)pixels, FileDataSize);

    unsigned char tmpRGB = 0; // Swap buffer
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < FileDataSize; i += 3)
    {
        tmpRGB = pixels[i];
        pixels[i] = pixels[i + 2];
        pixels[i + 2] = tmpRGB;
    }

    // Set width and height to the values loaded from the file
    unsigned int w = bmpInfo->biWidth;
    unsigned int h = bmpInfo->biHeight;

    /TODO:***************GENERATING TEXTURES*******************/

    // Output a successful message
    std::cout << "Texture \"" << path << "\" successfully loaded.\n";

    // Delete the two buffers.
    delete[] datBuff[0];
    delete[] datBuff[1];
    delete[] pixels;

    return 0; // Return success code 
}
```

now it's not reading the pixels , the variable pixels is always 0, what am doing wrong here?

EDIT: values of `bmpInfo`

```
biSize  40  
biWidth 1024    
biHeight    1024    
biPlanes    1   
biBitCount  32  
biCompression   0
biSizeImage 0   
biXPelsPerMeter 0
biYPelsPerMeter 0
biClrUsed   0
biClrImportant  0
```

Comment: Have you tried printing all the fields in the two headers to see if they look valid? Also (and this may not be related to your issue), I don't see why you need `datBuff` or why you need to do heap allocation of the headers. You could simply declare the headers as `BITMAPFILEHEADER bmpHeader;` and `BITMAPINFOHEADER bmpInfo;`.

Comment: @Michael both headers have valid data!

Comment: Ok, well, can you edit your question and list the values you're getting e.g. for `biWidth`, `biHeight` and `biBitCount` for one of the images you're testing with?

Comment: @Michael I have edit it , and added the values.

Comment: Your code works just fine for me using various bitmaps I had laying about.  Have you tried one a different one? Preferably one saved in Paint?

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware that's wired it worked on the bmp saved by paint , but not on this one http://www.2shared.com/photo/h0gX4EuT/T1_online.html

Answer (score 1):

Based on our conversion MixedCoder, I think that bitmap you're trying to load was not correctly saved.  We can see that

bmpHeader.bfOffBits = 54;

that means if we subtract our fix size of 14 for the header.  That leaves us 40 bytes for the bmpInfo which by definition is the size of the BITMAPINFOHEADER.  So we can rule out some misalignment problem.

I would just saved that image again using Paint and load it that way.

Answer (score 1):

The biSizeImage entry correctly may be left at zero for RGB bitmaps. Microsoft documents that behavior [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183376(v=vs.85).aspx). In that case, you would have to use a different calculation, using biWidth and biHeight.

So the bitmap you are testing with is not necessarily flawed, and a general purpose BMP reader should be prepared for this case.

Comment: yeah thanks , that's seems to be the case , but do you have that calculation or a site where I can find it?

Comment: Here is an excerpt from a program that seems to work well. `long pixelMem = m_fileSize - sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) - sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);` This of course assumes that it is reading from a plain BMP file, as opposed to BMP data embedded within a larger file.

Comment: I don't have code handy to compute pixmap size based on height and width, but in such a calculation you would have to remember that row length is always rounded up to the next multiple of 4, and pixels may come in a variety of sizes depending on the color model, indexing, and bit depth. It is not a trivial calculation.